# How can I seperate objects within objects (which are not touching each other) into independent ones?

Tags: objects

[image: Cubes created by using the mirror-modifier]

^
I've got those beautiful cubes to run a physiks simulation, but obviously they are one object so I they can't move independently.
I want each of them to be a single object.
Is it possible to split all of them simultaneously?

Comment: It does, as I searched whether there was something similar I didn't find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to edit mode, press 'A' to select every cube, then Press 'P', And select "separate by loose parts. This will take a little time to calculate, but it will work.